# ACF repeater field not rendering the rows

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this website that I'm working on for a client. I jumped into the project and I have to create the accordion on the template file for specific pages. I just started getting deeper into PHP so I found a solution online in this article https://wpbeaches.com/create-an-acf-repeater-accordion-in-wordpress/
Now, my problem is this:
I created the repeater field with two subfields https://prnt.sc/xfg3lv and I choose that it only shows on this page template https://prnt.sc/xfg6lw
Then I created the fields on the actual page with that template https://prnt.sc/xfgdhp and inserted that piece of code from the article into the template file. Of course, I modified the names with my field names. The problem is that on the front it is not showing the rows even if they exist and just skips to the else statement. I will paste the complete code of that template page so if anyone can help it would be awesome. I'm busting my head for two days now on this issue.

The code (I marked where my code starts and ends):

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Services
*
**/
global $post;
      $post_slug = $post->post_name;
      $grandParent_title=get_page(get_ancestors($post->ID,'page')[0] )->post_title;
      $grandParent_Image=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_ancestors($post->ID,'page')[0] )) ;
      get_header();



global $wp;

$current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
$url_slug=explode('/', $current_slug);

$uri_string=$url_slug[1];
$_SESSION['current_url']=$uri_string;


function find_string_in_array ($arr, $string) {

    return array_filter($arr, function($value) use ($string) {
        return strpos($value, $string) !== false;
    });

}

if(find_string_in_array ($url_slug, 'poly')==true)
{
  $nav_theme_location='polystyrene';
  $BannerClass='';
  $post_type='polystyrene';
  $galleryClass='';
}elseif(find_string_in_array ($url_slug, 'fiber')==true){
  $nav_theme_location='fiberglass';
  $BannerClass='fiberbanner';
  $post_type='fiberglass_type';
  $galleryClass='fiber';
}elseif (find_string_in_array ($url_slug, 'wood')==true) {
  $nav_theme_location='woodwork';
  $BannerClass='woodworkbanner';
  $post_type='woodworks';
  $galleryClass='wood';
}
elseif (find_string_in_array ($url_slug, 'creative')==true) {
  $nav_theme_location='creative_production';
  $BannerClass='creativebanner';
  $post_type='creative_services';
  $galleryClass='creative';

}elseif (find_string_in_array ($url_slug, 'f-and-b')==true) {
  $nav_theme_location='fb';
  $BannerClass='fandbbanner';
  $post_type='creative_services';
  $galleryClass='';

}else{
    $nav_theme_location='';
    $BannerClass='';
    $post_type='';
   $galleryClass='';

}
?>
<section class="banner inner-banner <?= $BannerClass;?>">
    <!-- <div class="bannerBox" style="background-image: url(<?php // echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url())?get_the_post_thumbnail_url():;?>)"> -->
  
    <div class="bannerBox" style="background-image: url(<?= (get_the_post_thumbnail_url()!='')?get_the_post_thumbnail_url():$grandParent_Image;?>)">
        <div class="bannerContent">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <h1><?= $grandParent_title;?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



<section class="secondrynavigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="innerMenu">
        
               <?php
                  $args=array(
                     'theme_location'=>$nav_theme_location,
                     'container'     =>false,
                     'menu_class'    =>'',
                      );
                  wp_nav_menu($args);
                  ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
            
            <section class="pad">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="innerHeading">
                        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
                        <p><?php
                        $content_post = get_post($post->ID);
                        echo $content = $content_post->post_content;?></p>

       

                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="gallery <?= $galleryClass?>">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php 
                           // echo $post_type;exit;
                                $loops = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=> -1,
                                                            'post_type' => $post_type, 
                                                            'orderby' => 'id',
                                                            'order' => 'asc',
                                                            'category_name'=>$uri_string));
// echo "<pre>";
  //                              print_r($loops);exit;
                                if($loops->have_posts()):
                                while ($loops->have_posts()) :
                                $loops->the_post();
                              global $post;
                              $post_slug = $post->post_name;
                             ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <a href="<?= get_permalink();?>">
                                    <div class="galleryBox">
                                        <div class="overlay">
                                            <p><i>Read More</i></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(<?= get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>)"></div>
                                        <div class="galleryText">
                                            <h5><?php the_title();?></h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile;
                            endif;?>
                            
                        
                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            
            <!--MY CODE-->
            
                <?php
    if( have_rows('services_accordion') ):
    
    
    // loop through the rows of data for the tab header
    while ( have_rows('services_accordion') ) : the_row();
        
//      $title = get_sub_field('services_title');
//      $description = get_sub_field('servises_description');

    ?>
    
        <button class="accordion"><?php echo get_field('services_title'); ?></button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p><?php echo get_field('services_description'); ?></p>
        </div>    
        <?php
    endwhile; 

else :


    echo 'In progress';

endif; ?>

<!--MY CODE END-->
            
       
<?php get_footer();?>
```

In the end this is the result on the page https://prnt.sc/xfh0z7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your content into:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

// all your content related to the post including repeater code.

<?php endwhile; // End of the loop.?>
```

This way repeater will be in scope of your current post/page. Alternatively you can indicate post id as an argument in the repeater function.

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the problem!!!
Can you please explain why is this necessary since this is a template for a specific post type and also for a specific page template? Do I always need to check if there are posts before I can initiate a loop like this?

Comment: the_post(); sets all post related variables there so if you look at any standard page pr post template it also has those lines of code around the content related to the post. Probably wordpress codex can explain things better than I can so you can just look up the_post function there and what it does :)